# Text in the same line after using \pstart in reledmac package

Tags: paragraphs, reledmac

I would ask if it is possible to keep the text in the same line without starting a new paragraph right after `\beginnumbering` and `\pstart` with `reledmac` package.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible, and it won't be. The implementation of linenumbering of reledmac require paragraphe breaking.

You can imitate your need using `\startlock` … `\endlock`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend,noeledsec,series={A}]{reledmac}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\lockdisp{last}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\startlock Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,     consectetur adipiscing elit.
Mauris varius vehicula massa ut blandit.
Integer rhoncus purus vitae lorem facilisis accumsan.
Maecenas dignissim massa pharetra,     iaculis eros pharetra,     consequat ipsum.
Aliquam erat volutpat.
Nullam varius nisl eu massa rhoncus gravida.
Phasellus ac aliquam tortor.
Integer non nunc et arcu malesuada ullamcorper at eu lacus.
Proin ac dolor euismod,     pellentesque orci sit amet,     aliquam risus.
Nullam porttitor,     eros vitae vulputate aliquam,\endlock % now,     numbering is starting 
eros metus aliquet metus,     ut finibus enim dui at metus.
Nulla mollis auctor ligula,     ut egestas lectus auctor et.
Cras orci orci,     congue ultricies dolor at,     imperdiet vestibulum massa.
Proin non ex sapien.
Etiam blandit et libero non viverra.
In pulvinar dictum enim.
Morbi dignissim lacinia euismod.
Vestibulum sed condimentum lectus.
Sed ac orci et augue pulvinar pulvinar vitae vitae justo.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
Ut ullamcorper dapibus purus,     a vulputate nisi pulvinar at.
Praesent quis ex finibus,     congue elit id,     laoreet mauris.
Ut non justo nec est faucibus lacinia.
Fusce nisi est,     euismod quis tortor quis,     pellentesque iaculis mi.
In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
Fusce tempor orci sit amet viverra facilisis.
Donec id euismod tellus.
Proin congue,     mauris a imperdiet mollis,     tortor urna ultrices purus,     nec commodo orci eros vel lectus.
Integer finibus,     mauris sed pellentesque tristique,     ante mauris facilisis augue,     vel tempor erat elit eget orci.
Integer ornare,     justo sed aliquam porttitor,     nisl nulla semper enim,     et euismod arcu massa maximus lorem.
Sed elementum est viverra nisi cursus,     sagittis pulvinar nisi interdum.
Phasellus euismod eu quam sit amet rutrum.
Curabitur ex arcu,     efficitur id pellentesque sit amet,     placerat non diam.
Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
Sed tincidunt enim velit,     vitae rhoncus est fermentum nec.
Nullam interdum ultricies massa venenatis pretium.
Sed accumsan libero ut nunc sagittis,     at ornare tellus tristique.
Pellentesque posuere velit purus,     quis maximus tellus blandit id.
Aenean aliquam erat eu tristique gravida.
Maecenas ac nulla quis magna posuere luctus.
Nam ac tellus dolor.
Phasellus eu lacinia orci.
Fusce ac vehicula velit.
Cras vitae rutrum magna.
Nam et libero ac erat varius dignissim.
Vivamus euismod,     quam id maximus tincidunt,     lectus leo aliquam libero,     eu ullamcorper dolor ipsum quis leo.
Duis in orci at felis placerat feugiat.
In porttitor elementum lorem,     at venenatis augue faucibus quis.
Vivamus luctus vulputate odio eget porta.
In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
Nulla magna ex,     dictum et quam ac,     mollis congue odio.
Fusce nec mattis lacus.
Curabitur molestie,     eros at malesuada placerat,     dui eros tempor risus,     nec iaculis lectus tellus eu dui.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```